# Flight distance of light bullet vs heavy bullet

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, aerodynamics

#### The Problem

We have argued with the brother, whether the heavier of lighter bullet will fly further.

Intuitively, the lighter bullet has more velocity $v$ and can cover more distance before it falls on the ground.
However, in case of friction with air, it will lose momentum faster. A heavier bullet has more inertia to the mass, in some sense.

#### The Model

I consider the situation, where both bullets are of the same sizes and shape, and the only difference is the density - hence the friction force is the same in both cases.

I suppose, that the friction force is proportional to square of bullet's velocity:
$$
F = -k \dot{x}^2
$$

$k$ is a coefficient, depending on the size of the bullet, air density, other factors.

#### Some computations

The time to fall on the ground ($h$-height above the ground):
\begin{equation}
T = \sqrt{\frac{2 h}{g}}
\end{equation}
Equation of motion for the bullet:
\begin{equation}
m \ddot{x} = -k \dot{x}^2 
\quad \rightarrow \quad
- \frac{\ddot{x}}{\dot{x}^2} = 
\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{1}{\dot{x}}\right)
= \frac{k}{m}
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\dot{x}} = C + \frac{k t}{m} = \frac{1}{v_0} + \frac{k t}{m}
\end{equation}
Integration over $t$ gives:
\begin{equation}
x = \int \limits_{0}^{T} \frac{dt}{\frac{1}{v_0} + \frac{k t}{m}} = 
\frac{m}{k}  \left(
\ln \left(\frac{1}{v_0} + \frac{k T}{m}\right) -
\ln \left(\frac{1}{v_0}\right)
\right) = 
\frac{m}{k}
\ln \left(1 + \frac{k v_0 T}{m} \right)
\end{equation}

#### Numerics

I've taken values from [here](https://nutsboltman.blogspot.com/2013/06/blog-post_838.html) - Russian source, I apologize.

There is a comparison between lighter and heavier bullet:

- $m = 0.2g$ $\quad v = 129 \ m/s$
- $m = 0.3g$ $\quad v = 110 \ m/s$

The first value is the mass of the bullet and the second is the initial velocity of the bullet. I assume, that the height in the initial moment of bullet above the ground is $1.6m$.

In the equation for the distance of the bullet flight, there is still an unknown friction coefficient, which is not as simple to estimate.

I have made a plot of the flight distance $x(k)$ for different values of $k$.

[image]

From here one can see, that for large friction - heavier bullet flies further, whereas for small, lighter covers larger distance. Quite expectable.

Which of these two cases is more likely to occur on practice?

Comment: Great, well researched question!

Comment: The T you calculated is for free fall without friction. But  I guess it is a good approximation if the bullet is fast enough.

Comment: In addition, there is an approximation associated with the horizontal velocity: $k|r|^2$ is nonlinear. Increased horizontal velocities are associated with increased vertical drag.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny yeah, indeed. I have neglected the friction for the free fall, since the friction on the fall from height 1.6m will barely affect the time in case the medium is air (for dense it can influence a lot).